# Write session data to database

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am creating a mini shopping cart, and I was wondering if there is a way to get the data from the sessions and write it to the database.
The user-selected parts are supposed to be added to their cart. Once they are done, how would I get the data that was stored into the session, and write it to the database so that their cart is still there when they login another time?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
$quantity = mysql_query('SELECT partID, quantity, catergory FROM computerparts WHERE partID=' . mysql_real_escape_string((int) $_GET['add']));
while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_array($quantity)) {
    if ($quantity_row['quantity'] != $_SESSION['index_' . $_GET['add']]) {
        $_SESSION['index_' . $_GET['add']]+='1';
    }
}
header('Location: ' . $page);
}

 if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
$_SESSION['index_' . (int) $_GET['delete']] = '0';
header('Location: ' . $page);
}

function cart() {
$total = "";
$sub = "";
foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value > 0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 6) == 'index_') {
            $id = substr($name, 6, (strlen($name) - 6));
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT partID, partName, price FROM computerparts WHERE partID=' . (int) $id);
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price'] * $value;
                echo $get_row['partName'] . 'x' . $value . '@ &pound;' . $get_row['price'] . '=' . $sub . '<a href="index.php?delete=' . $id . '">Delete</a> <br />';
            }
        }
        $total += $sub;
    }
}
if ($total == 0) {
    echo 'Your cart is empty';
} else {
    echo 'Total: &pound' . $total;
}
}
?>
```

To make thing easier Ive removed functionality from this website. There will be no purchase of any items all that happens is the user chooses what items he wants an save that info to be accessed any time he wants you could refer it to a specification. (specifications table) the items he has chosen are to be written to that table. with the current logged in userID.

Comment: what is the logic that you have tried

Comment: how do you determine `when the user done`? clicking logout? clicking `done` button? or just leave the page?

Comment: So what parts of your code do you want to add to your database, and in what way and method?

Comment: I don't think you are using sessions effectively. Or at the very least, you are not starting your session at the top of the code or showing where info is stored in the the session global.  Maybe it would be easier to debug if you had a specific session key for cart data, like `$_SESSION[cart]`?

Comment: by clicking done.
@think123 all i need written to the database is the partIDs(items selected) together with the current userID. Probably looking like this

Comment: @Anthony the sessions have been set already. the user had to be logged in to select items i couldnt just include the rest of the code

Comment: @Fadamie - I figured. But it would still help clean up your code if you dedicated a Session key to all things related to the cart. Right now, it looks like you are looping through all session variables, which might include login time, user name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fadamie

You are thinking to store the session data in database because if the user add item in it's cart and after that he logout without purchasing item from Your cart.

then next time he comes then we have to display that item to him like (You have added that item in cart but not purchased...)

I think this is Your logic... for that i have one answer..

You can store that particular purchase item in your purchase_item_by_user table with the "flag type "Pending" .

So every time you have to check in the list if there would be item in the Pending List...(you can also check with the particular date or time..)

After that When User Purchase that item You can make it's flag changed to "Puchased" or if User Cancel that item then you can set the Flag "Cancelled"..

This Will help You...
Thanks,
Tarun Malpani...

Comment: Thanks for the advice..
But its actually more basic than that. There will be no purchase of any items all that happens is the user chooses what items he wants an save that info to be accessed any time he wants you could refer it to a specification. (specifications table) the items he has chosen are to be written to that table. with the current logged in userID.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have already stored the values you would like in your session array.

In that case since the data is stored in the session, If the session is still active you can access the values via : `$_SESSION['cartItem']`

Then to store these values in a database check this link:

[**PHP and Writing to MySQL Databases**](http://bytes.com/serversidescripting/php/tutorials/phpandwritingtomysqldatabases/index.html). This is assuming it is a mysql database, I am not sure how or what sort of database you plan to connect to, please clarify this if it is something different.

---

Now the table itself, you will want to save the items selected, and utilize a value to determine if it has been purchased or not. You could prompt the user while they are leaving if they would like to save the purchase for a later date. If so, you could pass the value ('yes' in this case) via ajax to a php function which would then initiate sending the session values to a database with a column specifying that if the purchase is pending or complete.

Take a look at these links for futher clarification on how to acheive this:[**AJAX and PHP**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

---

This could also be achieved by checking if the 'cart' of the current user is full, if it is, when they leave you could automatically save the data to a database referencing the userID. So when that user logs back in the cart is saved and can be accessed again.

Check the `onbeforeunload` javascript event. you could utilize this to see if they are closing/asking if they would like to close and if so would they 'like to save their cart?', or simply just save that data to a database for it they login later, this could also be a function fired when they proceed to logout.

check this link for demo and further information: [**onbeforeunload event**](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm)

---

There are so many many ways to do this, I would not feel comfortable writing out a single method for said procedure. However this information is available, just remember to prepare your statements and/or utilize PDO and transfer things in a secure manner whenever possible.

links for reference: [**Prepared Statements**](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/), [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

*hisses angrily at PHP